Could a zigbee device be updated via software to support thread?
It's known that zigbee and thread use the same physical layer, just the application layer is different. Given that, is it theoretically possible to do a software/firmware update to a zigbee device and make it thread?

theoretically, anything is possible

There may be different memory requirements (flash and/or RAM) which may mean that some devices could be and others couldn’t.
